# extend session of Liferay when performing AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, session-state, liferay-6

I created a portlet that uses AJAX every function.
That is, the portlet is only rendered once and i didnt utilize processAction or the like.

Is there a way to extend the user's session using built in Liferay function using javascript?

I tried

```
Liferay.Session.extend();
```

but it does not seem to work..

I also tried a solution in the ICEfaces forum, which is

```
    if (Liferay.Session._stateCheck) {
           window.clearTimeout(Liferay.Session._stateCheck);
           Liferay.Session._stateCheck = null;
         }
         Liferay.Session.init({
           autoExtend: false,
           timeout: Liferay.Session._timeout,
           timeoutWarning:  Liferay.Session._warning
           });jQuery.ajax({url: Liferay.Session._sessionUrls.extend});
```

also not working..

I put those blocks of code whenever the user clicks a button

Any tip would greatly help..

Comment: `Liferay.Session.extend();`  is the answer, i didnt notice that the session is extended when testing the code

Comment: Hi, please create answer and put your solution from comment to it, and accept it. That way people will immediately know that there is solution for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same issue and solved it.
The main idea is to override session.js into ext-plugin, and add some additional method:

```
extendExternal: function() {
  var instance = this;

  if (instance != undefined) {
    instance.extend();
  }
}
```

also setCookie method should be updated:

```
 setCookie: function(status) {
   var instance = this;

   var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

   var options = {
      secure: A.UA.secure,
      path: "/"
   };

   A.Cookie.set(instance._cookieKey, status || currentTime, options);
 }
```

In order to use the same cookie path for each page.

And some global ajax event can be used for 'automatical' call of extendExternal method:

```
AUI().use('event', function(A){
 A.on('io:start', function(transactionid, arguments){
   if (Liferay.Session._cookieKey != undefined && Liferay.Session._cookieKey != null) {
     if (arguments != 'sessionExtend') {
       Liferay.Session.extendExternal();
     }
   }
 });
});
```

in this case extend method have to be updated with:

```
// added in order to differentiate session extend ajax calls and other ajax call, to     avoid infinit loop
 A.io.request(instance._sessionUrls.extend, {
    arguments: 'sessionExtend'
 });
```

You can check solution [here](http://java-liferay.blogspot.com/2012/05/extending-liferays-session-by-ajax-call.html).

Comment: Consider improving this answer to contain more than just a link. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 1):

Liferay.Session.extend(); is the answer, i didnt notice that the session is extended when testing the code