# Not able to extend liferay session programatically

Tags: javascript, ajax, session, liferay

I have been looking for a solution using which I can extend the liferay session when I do AJAX calls on my page. I found out that we can use Liferay.session.extend() to extend the liferay session. This I found out at [extend session of Liferay when performing AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509960/extend-session-of-liferay-when-performing-ajax-call)

But am not able to call the extend method, in console I get the error Liferay.session is not defined.

What would be the problem?

Comment: Hope you wrote the call `Liferay.session.extend()` in this script tag `<aui:script use="liferay-session"> ... </aui:script>`.

Comment: I called it inside a function which I have written in a JS file

Answer (score 1):

If you are making the call in a JSP than you can make the call inside the tag `<aui:script>` like this:

```
<aui:script use="liferay-session">
    Liferay.session.extend();
</aui:script>
```

Or

```
<aui:script use="liferay-session">
    function myCustomSessionExtend() {
        Liferay.session.extend();
    }
</aui:script>
```

---

Or if you are using a **separate javascript file** (`*.js`) then I think the following should work:

```
AUI().use('liferay-session', function(A) {
    Liferay.session.extend();
});
```

Or

```
function myCustomSessionExtend() {

    AUI().use('liferay-session', function(A) {
        Liferay.session.extend();
    });

}
```

From Liferay 6.0 onwards Liferay uses Alloy UI as there default javascript library.
Alloy UI has a concept of **sandboxing** (the `AUI().use (function(A) { ... });` creates a sandbox i.e. an isolated area for object) and **modularity** (it loads modules only when required, so `liferay-session` is one such module created using Alloy UI).

For more information you can view [this blog](http://www.liferay.com/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/alloyui-working-with-elements-and-events) and [this document](http://www.liferay.com/c/document_library/get_file?groupId=14&folderId=11324913&name=175608).

Hope this would help resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried your solution for the separate javascript file (*.js), but unfortunately it didn't work. What might be the reason? I am getting the same error- Liferay.Session not declared